# "Who does have the key of the room" or "whom does have the key of the room?"

Tags: grammar

I'm looking for the person who has the key of the room, and I have a doubt how to ask it (with **who** or **whom**)

> *"**Who** does have the key of the room"

or

> "**whom** does have the key of the room?"

Comment: A really simple rule for figuring out if you should use *who* or *whom*:  Try replacing it with "he" or "him" and see which one is correct.  If it's *he*, use *who*; if it's *him*, use *whom*.  So for this one: *He does* or *Him does*?  Obviously it's *he does*, so you should use "who".

Answer (score 1):

*Whom* is an object pronoun, so it can't be used as a subject of a sentence.

It can be the object of a preposition:

You can say:

> To whom does the key of the room belong?

Note that *who/whom* isn't really a thing anymore in English, so you can always use *who*.

Comment: Yeah, but if we lose *whom* we lose a great joke.  *Knock, knock.*  Who's there?  *To.*  To who?  *No, it's **to whom**.*